# How to use WebClient.DownloadString on a website that uses SSL?

Tags: c#, webclient

I know, this question has been posted a couple of times before, but I didn't get a clear answer/find a solution. I'm simply using WebClient.DownloadString on a website that uses SSL. Whenever I run my program, I get a "404 not found" error. I tried my program on a website that doesn't use SSL, and it worked perfectly.

Here's my code:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
string webData = webClient.DownloadString("https://example.com?user=" + listBox1.Items[currentIndex]);
```

I'm trying to make my program compatible with websites that use SSL. Does anyone have any examples on how to do this? Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString()` *does* support websites that use SSL. If the server returned a 404 error, that either means that the resource you're requesting doesn't exist or the web server is incorrectly configured to handle SSL requests as you desire.